# Android mobile phone as a microphone for TS3

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, audio, vlc-media-player, microphone

I use my mobile phone as a microphone for my laptop because the audio quality of my laptop microphones is terrible and I would like a cheap alternative. I use the app "Wireless Mic" to record and VLC to receive the stream. I use the Windows Stereomix recording devices to pass the whole to TS3. My questions are :

1.) How do I reduce the latency of the recordings (caching is already 0ms)

2.) How do I prevent myself from hearing? ()

Comment: Why not buy an [external microphone](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/insignia-usb-microphone/6063105.p?id=1219184621556&skuId=6063105) for your laptop? It would be a lot less trouble than what you're going through now. You also have the option of buying a headset.

Answer (score 0):

There is a virtual mixing board called [Voicemeeter](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Voicemeeter/) that allows you more control over the paths your audio takes. I use it to mix my USB mic with a sample playing app and pipe that to Skype. It gives you some virtual audio in and out jacks, so maybe that is a way to do it. On the other hand you could also simply get a mic for ca. 20 $/€/£ or a somewhat decent headset. If your laptop has no or only a crappy line-in, take a look at USB mic/headsets or maybe bluetooth.